# using tensorflow inside docker with gpu

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I'm trying to use tensorflow in docker, following the instructions at

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

I have docker 19.03 installed on a centos 7.7.1908 machine, and I can run nvidia-smi

```
docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.1-base nvidia-smi
```

my understanding is that the use of nvidia-docker is deprecated. then I download tensorflow

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-py3
```

or

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:devel-gpu
```

but when I run one of them

```
docker run -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-py3 python -c "import tensorflow as tf;"
```

I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' failed to
>   resize tty, using default size

what am I missing?

well, I've since found out that

```
latest-gpu-py3
```

allows me to import tensorflow, whereas

```
latest-devel-py3
```

doesn't. I'd've thought that all these images would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"devel" image contains tensorflow sources, see: https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/

Quote:

> devel images come with Bazel and are ideal for developing changes to
>   TensorFlow at master. /tensorflow_src includes the TensorFlow source
>   tree at the latest nightly commit where the Pip package built
>   successfully in the container. We no longer provide images for
>   developing on top of older versions of TF (1.12.0 was the last release
>   where this was the case).

Comment: okay, I see. it just didn't occur to me that the devel branch only had the source, and didn't include a compiled version too. thanks.

Comment: ok, then what is the image for tensorflow with gpu then?